# How to import a specific data from all the columns into a single array

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need to import a list of names from the SQLite Database (where it is stored ) in form of an array . Is this the right way to do it

Code for Database

```
public String queryAll() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String [] columns = new String [] {KEY_NAME};
    Cursor point = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iName = point.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

    for(point.moveToFirst();!point.isAfterLast();point.moveToNext()){
        result = result + point.getString(iName);
    }
    return result;
```

Code to where I should import the data to

```
    DBContact info = new DBContact (this);
    info.open();
    String data[] = info.queryAll();
    info.close();
    NewContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddContact);
```

I am a beginner , anything would help a lot.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String[] queryAll() {
    String [] columns = new String [] {KEY_NAME};
    Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            final int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
            List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                names.add(cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex));
            }
            return names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have been working on that code. Turns out my application is crashing because the above code initially has no data and hence returns nothing . How do I prevent it ??

Comment: You have to check the return value of `queryAll()` method, like `String[] result = queryAll(); if (result != null) { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you again. Also I have the issue how to arrange it in ascending order.How to overcome this .Iam new to android programming so plz dont mind while answering my silly ques

Comment: Replace appropriate line with `Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_NAME + " ASC");` See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: thanks a lot

See if you can help in this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597652/passing-intent-values-and-retrieving-data-from-sqlite-database/12599753#comment16983845_12599753

Comment: also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596639/secondary-activity-goes-the-main-activity-before-all-the-data-can-be-input#comment16977943_12596639


thanks a lot , again