# Passing Intent Values and retrieving data from SQLite database

Tags: android, android-intent

I have written a application similar to Contacts in android. I have a few items in my list , when I click them , I get the information from a data base and display in another view.But when I click on one of the names in list view , I get an empty screen(emulator goesblank) . Please help, i am new to android programming . all suggestions welcome

Thank You

```
public class Contacts extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    int NewContact_Request_Code = 1;
    Button newcontact;
    ListView listview;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "Contacts";
    int mInt = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contactview);
        // Set the content to contactview.xml

        // newcontact = NEW CONTACT button
        // listview = MyList List View
        newcontact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.baddcontact);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

        // Make a New Database
        DBContact info = new DBContact(this);
        // Open , get Information from database and close it
        info.open();
        String[] data = info.queryAll();
        info.close();
        // listview = getListView();
        listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        // Display the names
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Contacts.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                String nameclicked = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position)
                        .toString();
                Intent viewintent = new Intent(Contacts.this, ViewContact.class);
                viewintent.putExtra("name_clicked", nameclicked);
                startActivity(viewintent);

            }
        });
        newcontact.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent newintent = new Intent(Contacts.this, AddNewContact.class);
        // start actiivity for result - to get the name of the new contact
        startActivityForResult(newintent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // pass the value of the string via cursor and update the list
    }

}
```

ViewCOntact.class

```
public class ViewContact extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button ViewPPhone, ViewHPhone, ViewOPhone, EditContact;
    TextView ViewName;
    TextView ViewPersonalPhone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewcontact);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       String name = extras.getString("name_clicked");
        Long l = Long.parseLong(name);
        DBContact getdetails = new DBContact(this);
        getdetails.open();
        String returnedname = getdetails.getName(l);
        String returnedpphone = getdetails.getPphone(l);
        String returnedhphone = getdetails.getHphone(l);
        String returnedophone = getdetails.getOphone(l);
        getdetails.close();
        ViewName.setText(returnedname);
        ViewPPhone.setText(returnedpphone);
        ViewHPhone.setText(returnedhphone);
        ViewOPhone.setText(returnedophone);

        EditContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEditContact);
        EditContact.setOnClickListener(this);
        ViewPPhone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ViewPersonalPhoneNumber);
        ViewPPhone.setOnClickListener(this);
        ViewHPhone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ViewHomePhoneNumber);
        ViewHPhone.setOnClickListener(this);
        ViewOPhone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ViewOfficePhoneNumber);
        ViewOPhone.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.ViewPersonalPhoneNumber:
            Intent dialpersonalphone = new
            Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
            Uri.parse("returnedpphone"));
            startActivity(dialpersonalphone );
            break;

        case R.id.ViewHomePhoneNumber:
            Intent dialhome = new
            Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
            Uri.parse("returnedhphone"));
            startActivity(dialhome);
            break;

        case R.id.ViewOfficePhoneNumber:
            Intent dialoffice = new
            Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
            Uri.parse("returnedophone"));
            startActivity(dialoffice);
            break;

        case R.id.bEditContact:
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.contactlist.EDITCONTACT"));
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

LOGCAT

```
09-26 02:52:11.527: W/dalvikvm(1605): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.contactlist/com.example.contactlist.ViewContact}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:125)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:346)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:319)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at com.example.contactlist.ViewContact.onCreate(ViewContact.java:24)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-26 02:52:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1605):     ... 11 more
```

DATABASE CLASS

```
public class DBContact {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String KEY_PERSONALPHONE = "Personalnumber";
    public static final String KEY_HOMEPHONE = "Homenumber";
    public static final String KEY_OFFICEPHONE = "Officenumber";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Contacts";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "ContactList";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Instance of the class DbHelper
    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    public static final String[] KEYS_ALL = { DBContact.KEY_ROWID,
            DBContact.KEY_NAME, DBContact.KEY_PERSONALPHONE,
            DBContact.KEY_HOMEPHONE, DBContact.KEY_OFFICEPHONE };

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table ContactList (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "Name text not null, Personalnumber text not null, Homenumber text not null, Officenumber text not null); ";

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                ourDatabase.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ourDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ContactList");
            onCreate(ourDatabase);

        }

    }

    // Context of constructor withhin our Class
    public DBContact(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
    }

    // Opens the database
    public DBContact open() throws SQLException {
        // Constructor for DB Helper class takes in a Context
        // Context is passed in is "ourContext" for within our class

        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        // Passes in DB Name and Version
        // ourDatabase is of type SQLite DataBase
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // Closes the database connection
    public void close() {
        // refer to our DbHelper and close the SQLite DataBase Helper
        ourHelper.close();
        ourHelper = null;
        ourDatabase = null;
    }

    // Deletes the Row
    public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
        return ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, DBContact.KEY_ROWID + "="
                + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public String[] queryAll() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_NAME };
        Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            try {
        final int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            names.add(cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex));
        }
        return names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
   }
        }
        return null;
        //return columns;

    }

    /*public Cursor queryAll(){
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_NAME};
        return   ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(data == null){
        columns[0] = "NO CONTACTS PRESENT";
        return columns;
    }else{
        return columns;
    }


    }*/


    public long newRow(String name, String pphone, String hphone, String ophone) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues newvalue = new ContentValues();
        newvalue.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        newvalue.put(KEY_PERSONALPHONE, pphone);
        newvalue.put(KEY_HOMEPHONE, hphone);
        newvalue.put(KEY_OFFICEPHONE, ophone);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, newvalue);

    }



    public String getName(Long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                KEY_PERSONALPHONE, KEY_HOMEPHONE, KEY_OFFICEPHONE };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "="
                + 1, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String name = c.getString(1);
            return name;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getPphone(Long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                KEY_PERSONALPHONE, KEY_HOMEPHONE, KEY_OFFICEPHONE };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "="
                + 1, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String Pphone = c.getString(2);
            return Pphone;

        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getHphone(Long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                KEY_PERSONALPHONE, KEY_HOMEPHONE, KEY_OFFICEPHONE };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "="
                + 1, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String Hphone = c.getString(3);
            return Hphone;

        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getOphone(Long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                KEY_PERSONALPHONE, KEY_HOMEPHONE, KEY_OFFICEPHONE };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "="
                + 1, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String Ophone = c.getString(4);
            return Ophone;

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't name your variables with capital first letters

Comment: Ok . i will change them . I am very new , so I am clueless about most of the stuff

Comment: can you see buttons in ViewContact activity ?

Comment: No just a blank screen , when I click back button , then it crashes

Comment: post your stacktrace if it crashes

Comment: @njzk2, I have posted the LogCat. Please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

```
Long l = Long.parseLong(name);
```

is the problem..

```
String nameclicked = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position)
                    .toString();
```

here nameclicked  is a string

you are sending a string value and trying to parse it to number format.
So can i know why you are parsing nameClicked?

Comment: When I click a name in my list view , I am pulling the data for that name in database and showing it in another xml view . just like in contacts application in a phone . so i have to pass that name as parameter

Comment: i want to say you small thing. In your Contacts  class you are displaying string items as a list view and next you are getting the particular string on item click. In your ViewContact  class your are getting the string value and parsing to long which is not allowed.
Did you understand what i want to say?

Comment: Yes . But then how do i get the information from the data base for viewing the details of that contact and the name

Comment: well i can suggest you to get the id's too when you are getting the names in your Contacts  class and on click of the item pass this as an extra to other activity.
(I would suggest you to use a bean class and a baseadapter for this purpose (simply saying as am familiar with them sorry))

Comment: i would also suggest you to see this http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html which has the concept of using bean class

Comment: is there anything I can do a quick edit sort a thing . . so that I get some output atleast with very few changes in the code. I have a deadline in few hours so

Comment: use another method in your database class like somthing say queryids()
and in that write the logic for getting the ids from the database 
and call this method in your contacts class and store it in an integer array next on click of the list item get the value at the position from the new int array and pass it as a int extra to other activity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17182/discussion-between-user1693503-and-sharath-g)

Comment: i didnt get you... What are you left with?